# What language for Indie dev?

Tags: game-design, software-engineering

What would be a easy/fast language that would be good for an Indie developer for a FPS?

Java?
C#?
C++?
C?
Anything else that would be good?

Edit: (Platforms: Linux, Mac, Windows)

Comment: Question is not indy or not, question is which platform

Comment: Sorry 'bout that

Comment: "Racer or FPS or Platformer"? Those are all widely different games

Comment: "Question is not indy or not, question is which platform" I disagree. If it was only the platform, most people would just work with C.

Comment: This question is the game dev equivalent of "What wine goes with fish?". @LizardGamer All of your other questions have been pretty much exactly the same and you keep getting the same answer; It really doesn't matter which language as much as you think it does. Just pick one that works for your platform and go with it.

Comment: @klaim the question is about platform if you conform to the idea that you should write in the highest level language you can.

Comment: @Tetrad Well that would suppose that highest level languages are what makes you productive, but from practice I don't believe it at all. The languages you know best is clearly where you'll get things faster. That said, knowing well a language that allow high level constructs clearly helps you more than one that don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one you know better, and that works on the platform you want to build games on.

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to minimize the amount of code to ship your game on the 3 platforms, I guess you should use a standard like C++ or Java.

The advantage of C++ is that it is more fast at runtime, but you need to recompile your project for each platform, and sometimes use different libraries for OS specific features. Also you can control more easily how to handle your memory.

The advantage of Java is that it's generic, and if you don't know pointer arithmetic, easier to write.

I guess there are other solutions, like Flash, but these are the best solutions in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Go for the easy ones like C# or Java because you need it fast and you don't seem to mind which language to choose.

I think Java might be a good choice as it can run on all 3 platforms, and there is a good 3D engine [JMonkeyEngine](http://jMonkeyEngine%203.0%20%7C%20Java%20OpenGL%20Game%20Engine%20www.jmonkeyengine.com/). C# would go with the XNA framework I think, but it's restricted to Windows only and not as high-level as the JMonkeyEngine.